# What, precisely, were Dr. Jones' degrees?

Tags: indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark, the-last-crusade, the-temple-of-doom

Clearly it would seem that he has a doctorate in ARCHAEOLOGY - but what else? Not Theology, clearly, but Anthropology? History? Surely there's a novel or television episode or simple screen-cap that can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dr. Jones appears to hold a single doctorate in Archaeology from the Sorbonne in France, at least according to the [Lost Journal of Indiana Jones](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Journal_of_Indiana_Jones).

[image]   [image]

He attended Chicago University in the 1920s, presumably as an undergraduate and then as a master's student.

> INDY: (Ox) Listen to me pal, your name is Harold Oxley, you were born in Leeds, England. You and I went to school together at the University of Chicago, and you were never this interesting! My name is Indi- (though it pains him) My name is Henry Jones Junior
>
> <sub><sup>[Kingdom of the Crystal Skull - Original Screenplay](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/indy4b.pdf)</sup></sub>

Interestingly, we learn in [Indiana Jones and Peril at Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Peril_at_Delphi) that Indy was still doing his master's degree in Chicago when he traveled to the Sorbonne. He was told that his work at Delphi would be credited *towards* his degree.

> She waved a hand. "Don't worry. I'll take care of everything with the
> university. My emergency leave was approved, and you'll receive credit
> for field study. Your basic costs will be covered by my research
> budget. What do you say?"

After the "Delphi" incident, Indy never returned to complete his Masters (or more likely he was granted it solely on the basis of his additional credit) and went straight into his Doctorate, which he then completed in just two years.

> Belecamus pushed her plate to the side. "Look, Indy, if the tablet
> that has been discovered at Delphi is important, and I have the
> feeling it is, you'll be able to use it as the basis for your Ph.D.
> With your background, I'd say you can have your doctorate easily in
> two years. One year of intense study, then your thesis, and you'll be
> an archaeologist. If it doesn't work out, you fall back on
> linguistics."

This would make him **Professor Henry "Indiana" Jones, Jr., BSc, MSc (Chicago), PhD (Sorbonne).**

Comment: You never fail to impress.

Comment: I couldn't resist checking and there is indeed a School of Archaeology at the Sorbonne. Now, I am wondering if it was possible to start a PhD without a Master degree in France in the 20s (with a few exceptions, a Master degree - or equivalent - is currently required).

Comment: @Taladris It's Indy, I'm sure he found a way.

Comment: @Taladris - The Professor for that course personally dragged him out of university in Chicago, paid all of his expenses and promised him a doctorate if he'd help her with her expedition. On top of that he was solely responsible for then translating a key find, the crown jewel of her career as an archaeologist. I can't imagine that his lack of a masters degree would be an issue since it's not like he's just coming in the front door as an applicant.

Comment: @Valorum: Secretary: "Sorry Henry Jr. If you cannot show any proof of your Master degree, you cannot register for a PhD." Jones:"French administration, I hate these guys"